# WPF: refreshing value of a computed field in an item of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an issue with my WPF ObservableCollection.

I have an ObservableCollection (_additionalCosts) bound to a ListView which includes one readonly computed field based on the value of other properties in the item and, crucially, the value of another dropdown.

When I change the selected item of the dropdown I would like the computed field to refresh, which it is not doing at the moment.

My view class looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class BookingView : ViewBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<AdditionalCostView> _additionalCosts = new ObservableCollection<AdditionalCostView>();

    //..other members

    public ReferenceDataView SellPriceCurrency
    {
        get { return _sellPriceCurrency; }
        set
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SellPriceCurrency");
        }
    }

    //..other members
}
```

The items of the AdditionalCostView looks like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class AdditionalCostView : ViewBase, IEquatable<AdditionalCostView>
{
    //..other members
    private decimal? _margin;

    public decimal? Margin
    {
        get
        {
            if (_charterSellPriceCurrency == null)
                return null;

            if (_sellPrice.HasValue && _buyPrice.HasValue)
            {
                return _exchangeRateConverter.ConvertUsingExchangeRate(1, _sellPriceCurrency.Name, _charterSellPriceCurrency.Name, _sellPrice.Value) -
                       _exchangeRateConverter.ConvertUsingExchangeRate(1, _buyPriceCurrency.Name, _charterSellPriceCurrency.Name, _buyPrice.Value);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    //..other members
}
```

If you  need any more code, please let me know.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Does your computed field implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Perhaps you can post some of your code?

Comment: Ok I've added some code

Comment: Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `AdditionalCostView` class and call the name of the displayed property from the other related property too.

Comment: Can you direct me to a terse example of how to implement this? I'm a bit scared of INotifyPropertyChanged having not done WPF for about three years!

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is just about the least scary piece of WPF. :) You can do it!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your ViewBase class implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
From your code I understand that everytime that `_charterSellPriceCurrency` or `_sellPrice` or `_buyPrice` changes, the `Margin` property has to be recalculated.

This code consider just the _`charterSellPriceCurrency` changings, but it is easy to extend it to the other fields.

```
private YourType _charterSellPriceCurrency;
private Nullable<decimal> _margin;

public YourType CharterSellPriceCurrency 
{
    get
    {
        return _charterSellPriceCurrency;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (value != _charterSellPriceCurrency)
        {
            _charterSellPriceCurrency = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CharterSellPriceCurrency");
            CalculateMargin();
        }
    }
}

public Nullable<decimal> Margin
{
    get
    {
        return _margin;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (value != _margin)
        {
            _margin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Margin");
        }
    }
}

private void CalculateMargin()
{
    if (_charterSellPriceCurrency == null)
    {
        Margin = null;
        return;
    }

    if (_sellPrice.HasValue && _buyPrice.HasValue)
    {
        Margin = _exchangeRateConverter.ConvertUsingExchangeRate(1, _sellPriceCurrency.Name, _charterSellPriceCurrency.Name, _sellPrice.Value) -
                _exchangeRateConverter.ConvertUsingExchangeRate(1, _buyPriceCurrency.Name, _charterSellPriceCurrency.Name, _buyPrice.Value);
        return;
    }

    Margin = null;
}
```

The point is that you must notify to the UI that the Margin property changed, no matter if it is a read only property, if it changes you have to raise the event. Otherwise the UI can't be aware that it was recalculated.

Comment: But the Margin property is not updating when selecting a different item from the dropdown. The margin is only calculated if the dropdown has a value, you see, so when the currency is applied the margin in the should be calculated.

Comment: You have 2 solutions: 1) you can handle the [SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of your ComboBox. In the event handler you can call the `CalculateMargin` method. 2) You can bind the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your ComboBox to a property of your BookingView class. When the second property changes you can call the `CalculateMargin` method (which in this case can't be private).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can use computed fields in WPF. Let's say we have a property `Result` whose value depends on another property `Multiplier`. This is how you would get this scenario to work... please note that you *must* implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to get this to work:

```
public string Result
{
    get { return Multiplier * someFixedValue; }
}

public string Multiplier
{
    get { return multiplier; }
    set { multiplier = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Multiplier", "Result"); }
}
```

...

```
protected override void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, each time the `Multiplier` property is updated, the `Result` property will also be updated in the UI.

Comment: But the other properties in the element are not changing - it's a dropdown that is changing. This should trigger the margin in the list view to update.

Comment: That's the point... you need to make the other properties in the element change. You could do that by putting another property into the element and data bind that to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` so that it updates when the selected item is changed in the UI.