# How to raise a property change event to trigger other properties

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm not sure if my title is correct. i have two double properties that i bind to 2 textboxes, and i would like to calculate their total when one property changes. The RemainingBalance property is where i calculate, and displayed the total. i thought the code below will calculate when either GiftSold or GiftUsed value changed in UI. I even tried the twoway mode, but it still doesn't work.

```
    private double _giftSold;
    public double GiftSold
    {
        get { return _giftSold; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _giftSold)
            {
                _giftSold = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GiftSold");
                OnPropertyChanged("RemainingBalance");
            }
        }
    }

    private double _giftUsed;
    public double GiftUsed
    {
        get { return _giftUsed; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _giftUsed)
            {
                _giftUsed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GiftUsed");
                OnPropertyChanged("RemainingBalance");
            }
        }
    }

    public double RemainingBalance
    {
        get { return GiftSold - GiftUsed; }
    }
```

here is my xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Gift Sold  "/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding GiftSold, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Gift Used  "/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding GiftUsed, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Remain Balance  "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RemainBalance}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948259/how-to-raise-a-changed-event-in-wpf-on-property-of-data-item

Comment: If I understand your question right, you need to use **UpdateSourceTrigger** like this: `<TextBox Text="{Binding GiftSold, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`, also, as far as I know, in WPF bindings are `TwoWay` by default.

Comment: yes thank you...that worked perfectly

Comment: typo RemainBalance = RemaingBalance

Answer (score 0):

```
    private double _giftSold;
public double GiftSold
{
    get { return _giftSold; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _giftSold)
        {
            _giftSold = value;
            CalculateRemainingBalance();
            OnPropertyChanged("GiftSold"); 
        }
    }
}

private double _giftUsed;
public double GiftUsed
{
    get { return _giftUsed; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _giftUsed)
        {
            _giftUsed = value;
                CalculateRemainingBalance();
            OnPropertyChanged("GiftUsed");
        }
    }
}

private double _RemainingBalance;
public double RemainingBalance
{
    get { return _RemainingBalance }
}

private void CalculateRemainingBalance()
{
_RemainingBalance = GiftSold - GiftUsed;
 OnPropertyChanged("RemainingBalance");
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to bind a property it should defined as  DependencyProperty. Here is a solution for you:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private double _giftSold;
        public double GiftSold
        {
            get { return _giftSold; }
            set 
            { 
                _giftSold = value;
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GiftSoldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GiftSold",
                                        typeof(double),
                                        typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, GiftAny_Changed));
        private static void GiftAny_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow a = d as MainWindow;
            double dummy = a.RemainingBalance; // to call the "get" method
        }

        private double _giftUsed;
        public double GiftUsed
        {
            get { return _giftUsed; }
            set 
            { 
                _giftUsed = value;
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty GiftUsedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GiftUsed",
                                        typeof(double),
                                        typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, GiftAny_Changed));
        private double remainingBalance;
        public double RemainingBalance
        {
            get {
                remainingBalance = (double)GetValue(GiftSoldProperty) -
                    (double)GetValue(GiftUsedProperty);
                SetValue(RemainingBalanceProperty, remainingBalance);
                return remainingBalance; 
            }
            set
            {
                remainingBalance = value;
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RemainingBalanceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RemainingBalance",
                                        typeof(double),
                                        typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and the XAML

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Gift Sold  "/>
            <TextBox Width="119" Text="{Binding GiftSold, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Gift Used  "/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding GiftUsed, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="115"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Remain Balance  "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RemainingBalance, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" Width="81"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

By using DependencyProperty definitions you can inform other controls about that property changed. I also used same definition to handle PropertyChanged events.